# Ajax Iframe trigger click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

Hello fellow StackOverflow.
I need a favor on Ajax this time.

This is my Ajax code.

```
$('#contactForm1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var frm = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is not valid.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the iFrame code :

```
    <div class="iFrame"><input class="text" id="iframetarget1" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="500" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />
<div class="buttonContainer">
<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="501" />
```

So here's what I want the scenario to occur,
 1. Pass the information after the Ajax check the email to and submit the form.
 2. Submit the same email in the iFrame and submit it.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Are they in same domain?

Comment: @Fancyoung , Yes .
Actually they're in the same page.

Comment: i think its a typo you have a extra `<` with `input name="submit"` in html.

Comment: @Kartikeya, thanks for pointing that for me , typo.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `$(window.frames[0].document)` get iframe content, then operate it as  normal. Such  as:

```
$(window.frames[0].document).find('#iframetarget1').val(email);
$(window.frames[0].document).find('.submit').trigger('click');
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/du5sazay/1/

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong here.
My button is input but it's called by the ajax.
Can't I just fit these functions when the data === success?

Comment: Read your code again, it seems your problem isn't caused by iframe, but call `submit` function recursively. Could you provide a demo

Comment: But I don't understand the onclick function thou.

Comment: It's just a test,  just put js code into ajax success?

Comment: Didn't went through , nothing happened but the frm.submit triggered.
I attached a jsfiddle code.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/du5sazay/1

Comment: In the Jsfiddle ignore the function in the success cause I didn't update the jsfiddle.

Comment: u need click 'update' in jsfiddle to save your edit. `jsfiddle.net/du5sazay/1` is my version

Comment: I'm still facing some problem , my previous function didn't work..
Do you have a skype or something?

Comment: But it didn't pass to the iframe function @.@

Comment: Oh wait i realised the URL is changed , i need my PHP code lol

Comment: `url: '/echo/json/',` and `json: JSON.stringify({
                    status: 'success',
                    email: email
                }),` are just for fake data, php request couldn't be  called in jsfiddle because cross domain. Just change these line into your code, it should be ok.

Comment: So you change the button ID , cause my ID for the Ajax is based on the form.
Any other way?

Comment: It doesn't matter (see http://fiddle.jshell.net/du5sazay/10/), where's your `#contactForm1`? your ajax code is in root window or iframe ?

Comment: in the windows , but i need to call the iframe function in the same ajax.